# Commenting Python code in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am writing docs for some Python code and I can't insert comments into it properly.
There is a problem between what I write in a .rst file and what is displayed in a generated html. It looks like this :

.rst file :

```
.. sourcecode:: python  

    class Foo( argument_1, argument_2 ):           # argument_1 is blabla, arg2 is..

        def bar():                                 # method bar does ...
            print 'foo'                            # another comment

        def foo_bar():                             # foo_bar method explanation
            print 'foo_bar body'                   # ....
```

And in the generated .html file it looks just fine except that comments are unaligned:

.html file :

```
class Foo( argument_1, argument_2 ):         # argument_1 is blabla, arg2 is..

    def bar():                                  # method bar does ...
        print 'foo'                            # another comment

    def foo_bar():                             # foo_bar method explanation
        print 'foo_bar body'                 # ....
```

is there any way to fix that? I use gedit on Ubuntu 11.04 to write this docs. I've been playing a bit with tab's width, replacing tabs with spaces, but it didn't help.

Comment: I checked option 'replace tabs with spaces', so there is no mixup.

Comment: I can't reproduce this; in my generated HTML the comments are aligned.

Comment: You've tried copying and pasting the exact above code somewhere into your .rst file?